# ajax in laravel for create and update

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, crud

i used ajax for crud in laravel. when update or add data, add new row to list but return string 'undefined' and when refresh this page show real text.
**how to resolve this problem?**

**Controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $user_id)
{
        $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->update([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
        ]);

        if ($request->input('role') == 'admin'){
            $user = DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id', $user_id)->update([
                'role_id' => 2,
                'model_type' => 'App\User',
                'model_id' => $user_id,
            ]);
        } else {
            $user = DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id', $user_id)->update([
                'role_id' => 1,
                'model_type' => 'App\User',
                'model_id' => $user_id,
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json($user);
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr id="user{{$user->id}}" class="active">
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->hasRole('admin') ? 'Admin' : 'Author' }}</td>
        <td width="35%">
            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-detail open_modal" value="{{$user->id}}"> Edit </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete delete-user" value="{{$user->id}}"> Delete </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**js codes for ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    //get base URL *********************
    var url = $('#url').val();


    //display modal form for creating new user *********************
    $('#btn_add').click(function(){
        $('#btn-save').val("add");
        $('#frmusers').trigger("reset");
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });



    //display modal form for user EDIT ***************************
    $(document).on('click','.open_modal',function(){
        var user_id = $(this).val();

        // Populate Data in Edit Modal Form
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url + '/' + user_id,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#user_id').val(data.id);
                $('#name').val(data.name);
                $('#password').val(data.password);
                $('#email').val(data.email);
                $('#btn-save').val("update");
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });



    //create new user / update existing user ***************************
    $("#btn-save").click(function (e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })

        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            role: $('#role').val(),
        }

        //used to determine the http verb to use [add=POST], [update=PUT]
        var state = $('#btn-save').val();
        var type = "POST"; //for creating new resource
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();;
        var my_url = url;
        if (state == "update"){
            type = "PUT"; //for updating existing resource
            my_url += '/' + user_id;
        }
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type: type,
            url: my_url,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var user = '<tr id="user' + data.id + '"><td>' + data.name + '</td><td>' + data.email + '</td><td>' + data.role + '</td>';
                user += '<td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-detail open_modal" value="' + data.id + '">ویرایش</button>';
                user += ' <button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete delete-user" value="' + data.id + '">حذف</button></td></tr>';
                if (state == "add"){ //if user added a new record
                    $("#users-list").append(user);
                }else{ //if user updated an existing record
                    $("#user" + user_id).replaceWith( user );
                }
                $('#frmusers').trigger("reset");
                $('#myModal').modal('hide')
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });


    //delete user and remove it from TABLE list ***************************
    $(document).on('click','.delete-user',function(){
        var user_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: url + '/' + user_id,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#user" + user_id).remove();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: The update method returns boolean so essentially in all 3 blocks you are setting the `$user` to a boolean not an object

Comment: what's the solution?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update method returns boolean so essentially in all 3 blocks you are setting the $user to a boolean not an object.

So utilize tap() function

```php
public function update(Request $request, $user_id)
{
    $user = tap(User::where('id', $user_id)->first())
        ->update([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
        ]);

        if ($request->input('role') == 'admin'){
            DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id', $user_id)->update([
                'role_id' => 2,
                'model_type' => 'App\User',
                'model_id' => $user_id,
            ]);
        } else {
            DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id', $user_id)->update([
                'role_id' => 1,
                'model_type' => 'App\User',
                'model_id' => $user_id,
            ]);
        }

    //Or you can fetch the user record again User::find($user_id);
    //if you are not using tap()

    return response()->json($user->fresh());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how to resolve this problem in store method?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $userAuth = auth()->user();
    if($userAuth->hasRole('admin')){
        $user = User::insertGetId([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
        ]);

        if ($request->input('role') == 'admin'){
            $user = DB::table('model_has_roles')->insert([
                'role_id' => 2,
                'model_type' => 'App\User',
                'model_id' => $user,
            ]);
        } else {
            $user = DB::table('model_has_roles')->insert([
                'role_id' => 1,
                'model_type' => 'App\User',
                'model_id' => $user,
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json($user);
    }
```